# How to list all methods of an object in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, metaprogramming

How do I get the list of all methods from an object? I know I can get the object class in this way:

```
var className:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName( myObject );
var objClass:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName( className ) as Class;
```

It gives me an the class prototype, but and can't do anything with it...
In JavaScript I can iterate over the prototype of an object to get its properties and methods.
Is that possible in ActionScript 3? Do you any good source for metaprogramming/reflection over ActionScript 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) function.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to call the methods. This decribeType just serializes the object into XML.

Comment: @Eduardo. Yes, but if you have the object and you have the name of the method, you can call it. With the same syntax as in JS: `object[method](parameter);`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the operators (for ... in...) once you got the Class reference or the Object instance? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using FP 11+, this is an easier way to list all functions of a class in AS3.

```
var req = new URLRequest('');
trace(JSON.stringify(req))
```

It also works for data objects.